# How do i crop a image and fit the cropped part to the parent container

Tags: flutter

I am new to Flutter
I have an image that i want to add to my restaurant Cards, now the problem is that i want some cropped part of the image to be displayed(focus on ice cream)

I tried some ways and managed to come up with a sol -> which on decreasing width the image starts to crop from left and right whereas when I start decreasing the height instead of cropping it is resizing
Can anyone tell me if that is possible what I want or if I should crop the image itself before adding in assets?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:food_delivery_app/utils/globals.dart';

class RestaurantCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const RestaurantCard({super.key, required this.item});
  final CardItem item;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 160,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          const SizedBox(width: 15),
          Center(
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 120,
                  height: 150,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                    image: const DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage('./assets/restaurantImages/1.jpeg'),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                    boxShadow: const [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Color.fromARGB(144, 0, 0, 0),
                        blurRadius: 2,
                        offset: Offset(0, 1),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment.center,
                        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        colors: [
                          Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                          Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4),
                          Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
                          Colors.black.withOpacity(0.9),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            width: 17,
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  item.restaurantName!,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      '${item.rating} (${item.noOfRatings})',
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                    ),
                    const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.circle,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        size: 5,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      item.time!,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Text(
                  item.tags!,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 103, 106, 109)),
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      item.address!,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 103, 106, 109)),
                    ),
                    const Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.circle,
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 103, 106, 109),
                        size: 3,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      item.distance!,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Color.fromARGB(255, 103, 106, 109)),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                const Text('FREE DELIVERY'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {},
            child: const Icon(
              Icons.more_vert_rounded,
              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 151, 152, 155),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

For Images
https://imgur.com/a/jIjjBk2

Comment: try BoxFit.contain or BoxFit.fitHeight

Comment: @ArbiterChil Tried not achieving required results :'

Comment: For Stack child, use Position widget,

Comment: @YeasinSheikh position widget is gonna change the position on the stack, how is it gonna help in cropping the image from height and width?

Comment: image link is broken here , can you include the an image the thing you are trying to get

Comment: @YeasinSheikh [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_M0RZ07n3qZVPkN3Tenbahb6G7x2KXnZ?usp=sharing)

Comment: You can use `alignment` from `DecorationImage` ig